# Google Chart add data from array

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

Hi guys so I'm trying to draw a chart with Google chart

this is my code:

```
      google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['bar']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);


  function drawStuff() {

    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([


      ['', 'Total: '],


      [info["name"] , info["qn"]],  //first element
      [info["name"] , info["qn"]],  //second element


    ]);



    var options = {


      legend: { position: 'none' },

      axes: {

      },
      bar: { groupWidth: "80%" }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    // Convert the Classic options to Material options.
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  };
```

My question is: How can I insert data from an array to the chart?

PS: the first element is supposed to be the first element of the array and the second element is supposed to be the second one.

My array:

```
    var cont = 1;
var rowtbl = document.getElementById("tabella").rows.length;
rowtbl = rowtbl - 1; //number rows table
while(cont <= rowtbl){
    var nomi;
    var qnt;
    nomi = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[0].innerHTML;
    qnt = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[1].innerHTML;
    var info = {name: nomi, qn: qnt};
    cont = cont +1; 

}
```

Comment: can you post a portion of the `info` array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have an array of objects, similar to this...

```
var info = [
  {
    name: "Test 1",
    qn: 1
  },
  {
    name: "Test 2",
    qn: 2
  }
];
```

then you would access the elements as such...
1st element -- `info[0]`
2nd element -- `info[1]`

as for the object keys of each element, you can access two ways...
`info[0]["name"]`
-- or --
`info[0].name`

you can also use `Array.forEach` to add all the rows in a loop.

see following working example, the same rows are added twice,
just to show the different ways of adding rows...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: function () {

    var info = [
      {
        name: "Test 1",
        qn: 1
      },
      {
        name: "Test 2",
        qn: 2
      }
    ];

    var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
      ['', 'Total: '],
      // add each element manually
      [info[0]["name"] , info[0]["qn"]],  //first element
      [info[1]["name"] , info[1]["qn"]],  //second element
    ]);

    // add each element via forEach loop
    info.forEach(function(value, index, array){
      data.addRow([
        value.name,
        value.qn
      ]);
    })

    var options = {
      legend: { position: 'none' },
      bar: { groupWidth: "80%" }
    };

    var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
    chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
  },
  packages: ['bar']
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="top_x_div"></div>
```

**EDIT** -- based on code from comment

you can use `data.addRow` at the end of the `while` statement

note changes made to column headings for `data`

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
      callback: function () {
        var cont = 1;
        var rowtbl = document.getElementById("tabella").rows.length;
        rowtbl = rowtbl - 1;

        // use object notation for column headings
        var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          [{type: 'string', label: ''}, {type: 'number', label: 'Total: '}]
        ]);

        //number rows table
        while(cont <= rowtbl){
          var nomi;
          var qnt;
          nomi = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[0].innerHTML;
          qnt = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[1].innerHTML;
          var info = {
            name: nomi,
            qn: qnt
          };

          // add row to google data
          data.addRow([
            info.name,
            parseFloat(info.qn)
          ]);

          cont = cont +1;
        }

        var options = {
          legend: { position: 'none' },
          bar: { groupWidth: "80%" }
        };

        var chart = new google.charts.Bar(document.getElementById('top_x_div'));
        chart.draw(data, google.charts.Bar.convertOptions(options));
      },
      packages: ['bar']
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<table id="tabella">
  <tr>
    <th>Column 1</th>
    <th>Column 2</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 1</td>
    <td>1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 2</td>
    <td>2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Test 3</td>
    <td>3</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div id="top_x_div"></div>
```

Comment: var cont = 1;
 var rowtbl = document.getElementById("tabella").rows.length;
 rowtbl = rowtbl - 1; //number rows table
 while(cont <= rowtbl){
  var nomi;
  var qnt;
  nomi = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[0].innerHTML;
  qnt = document.getElementById("tabella").rows[cont].cells[1].innerHTML;
  var info = {name: nomi, qn: qnt};
  cont = cont +1; 

 }                                                                                                                  How can I use data stored in this array to create the chart? Thank you so much

Comment: no problem, see edit above. it would also be better to edit the question with the code from the comment...